# Определить количество символов для каждой строки в текстовом файле

Tags: python, текстовые-файлы

В текстовом файле для каждой отдельной строки определить количество в ней символов.

Пример:

```
Hello world!
Привет мир!
One, two, three
```

Результат:

```
13 symbols.
12 symbols.
16 symbols.
```

Я понял как посчитать количество символов для всего файла, но не могу понять как это сделать для каждой строки.

Мой код:

```
f1 = open('text.txt', 'r')
data = f1.read()
number_of_ch = len(data)
print(number_of_ch)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Открывайте файл в операторе `with` - важный навык аккуратного программирования.
2. Файл в Питоне перебирается по строкам без дополнительных усилий.
3. `print` выводит свои аргументы через пробел - простое форматирование в вашем случае.

Код:

```
# with open('text.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
# если вы хотите читать файл в кодировке UTF-8 на Windows
with open('text.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(len(line), 'symbols.')
```

Comment: По такому решению в консоли выдает по второй строке почему-то 21 символ, хотя должен выдавать 12 символов. Почему так?

Comment: Программа считает 1 символ на кириллице за 2

Comment: В какой кодировке файл? Какая операционная система? Какая версия Питона?

Comment: Если файл в `utf-8` и операционная система Windows и Питон свежий, то поменяйте чтение файла так: `open('text.txt', encoding='utf-8')`.

Comment: Благодарю! С наступающим новым годом!)

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте не через метод `read()`, а через `readlines()`.

Вот пример работы:

```
f1 = open('text.txt', 'r') # Открываем файл

for line in f1.readlines(): # Создаем цикл for. readlines() возвращает итератор.
    print(len(line)) # Печатаем длину каждой строки
```

Comment: `readlines` не возвращает каждую строку по очереди. этот метод возвращает все строи файла как элементы списка. а вот `readline`  возвращает каждую строку по очереди.

Comment: Спасибо. Исправил.